# How to connect SharePoint Online with Dynamics CRM Online using BDC?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, bdc, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to connect SharePoint Online with Dynamics CRM Online using BDC, but I'm not getting any results.
I am trying to use Accounts from CRM in SharePoint Online like a list.
When I have 100 accounts (customers) in CRM I want to export these accounts to SharePoint Online like a list. And when I will bed edited account in CRM the elements in the list will be updated (when I edited element on SharePoint list it will update in CRM).
Is there any possibility to connect in this way? If there is then what I should use - SharePoint Designer 2010, Visual Studio or do this on web interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Girish Raja provides a great overview on how to integrate CRM Online and SharePoint Point via BCS. His [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2011/06/16/teched-na-2011-session-recording-crm-and-sharepoint.aspx) includes a link to his video presentation from TechEd in May (go to minute 35 in video) along with a link to the source code/instructions.  His demo uses SharePoint on-premise but mentions that it will work with SharePoint Online once BCS is enabled. (which it is now).

Comment: Tried the particular approach as mentioned by Girish Raja. I get an error on last but one step, After authentication it says, _"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
Correlation ID:3914e3fc-cc2d-416e-b5a9-93c82a6cb16b
"_ . Anything i can do which solves this error? The CRMProxy is running fine, my credentials have all permissions, and my BDCM got created without any errors or warnings..

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

[Msdn Blog: Microsoft Dynamics CRM integration with SharePoint Online is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/11/07/microsoft-dynamics-crm-integration-with-sharepoint-online-is-here.aspx)

... this is how to do it:

> 1. Your Microsoft Dynamics CRM System Administrator must install the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 List Component
> 2. Once enabled, the Microsoft Dynamics CRM user can open an Account
> 3. Click on Documents – If the Account does not have a corresponding Document Library in SharePoint Online one is automatically created

Answer (score 0):

<del>Unfortunately this cannot be done at this time</del> - http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/2301.aspx

See codeulike's answer for more up to date information.

Comment: At the start of that thread, people are saying it isn't possible, but by page 3 of the thread they are saying that its working.